# Beer, baccarat and Bee Gees

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, language

> I can be found in a Bee Gees refrain
>   and in a baccarat deck.
>   Bavarian beer and in any old sayin',
>   arabs, Oman and Iraq.
>
> I start the name of an old Saudi king,
>   inside of his kingdom I'm twice.
>   I am involved when a hen does its thing,
>   or when you have been told the price.
>
> When you need God, you can use me at will,
>   children light matches in awe.
>   I'm there when you're lost, when you neuter or kill,
>   assert that your word is the law.

What am I?

Hint:

> Looking for a single consonant.

Hint 2:

> The king ruled until recently.

Hint 3:

> Iraq works as a clue on the fourth line, but Iran would not. Neither would Qatar.

Hint 4 and 5:

> Looking for a non-English letter.

Comment: If it weren't for the hint, the letter r13 (N) would have been a slam dunk of an answer...

Comment: Yeah, but I would have been facing a fine for an illegal use of the "knowledge" tag...

Comment: Is the answer rot13(M) ? Not sure though but it feels like it.

Comment: This is one of those where if you have the correct answer you know for sure :)

Comment: I can't help but feel rot13-ing individual letters, especially those two, is kind of ineffective...

Comment: @EightAndAHalfTails 19 more attemps. It must be one of it ;)

Comment: @jafe if you say that it's the right answer, I'll pay the fine for you ;P

Comment: @jafe I couldn't help myself, especially not after that second clue. Your cheque for the fine is in the mail...

Comment: I've gotta go to bed, so I don't have time to make an answer, and so I'm just gonna comment: is the answer Rot13(rcfvyba)?

Comment: @user477343 that's a vowel :)

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's right... the sleep is getting to me :P

Comment: @jafe, I feel like I'm working with you a lot this morning! Does my second answer receive more merit than my first one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you the letter

> [AYIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayin)

I can be found in a Bee Gees refrain

> A-a-a-a st**ayin**' alive, st**ayin**' alive

and in a baccarat deck.

> A deck of pl**ayin**g cards.

Bavarian beer and in any old sayin',

> It's found in **Ayin**ger Oktoberfest beer as well as in any old s**ayin'**

arabs, Oman and Iraq.

> The letter **Ayin** is found in each of these words, *but not in Iran or Qatar*.

I start the name of an old Saudi king,

> King Abdullah, who was King until very recently (2015) per the second hint; Abdullah begins not with an *alif* but with an **ayin** instead.

inside of his kingdom I'm twice.

> Saudi Arabia contains two letters **ayin**.

I am involved when a hen does its thing,

> That is, l**ayin**g eggs.

or when you have been told the price.

> When you're p**ayin**g.

When you need God, you can use me at will,

> This would be pr**ayin**g.

children light matches in awe.

> They're pl**ayin**g or displ**ayin**g something, or maybe even celebrating Hanukkah because **ayin** is a Hebrew letter as well. Also, they have to follow the rules, according to the principle of [Marit Ayin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marit_ayin). They could also be pr**ayin**g as well (prayer candles); or holid**ayin**g too. *Update from @jafe: this was intended to be children pl**ayin**g with fire.* Thanks for the update! :)

I'm there when you're lost, when you neuter or kill,

> When you're str**ayin**g, when you're sp**ayin**g, and when you're sl**ayin**g.

assert that your word is the law.

> When you're s**ayin**g it. *Update from @jafe: this was intended to be l**ayin**g down the law.* Thanks for the update x2! :)

Comment: Yep, this is it. I had a couple of other ones as the intended answer – rot13[cynlvat jvgu sver naq ynlvat qbja gur ynj] – but the ones you selected work as well :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the additional info, @jafe -- I've incorporated your suggestions into my answer! :D It was actually pretty neat learning about these foreign alphabets, I had no idea about either of the two I referenced before yesterday!

Answer (score 7):

I know this isn't

> a consonant, but to heck with it...are you the letter **A**??

I can be found in a Bee Gees refrain

> **A-a-a-a** st**a**yin' **a**live, st**a**yin' **a**live

and in a baccarat deck.

> The **A**ce, because baccarat uses a standard deck of cards.

Bavarian beer and in any old sayin',

> It's found in a l**a**ger as well as B**a**v**a**ri**a**n; as well as in **a**ny old s**a**yin'

arabs, Oman and Iraq.

> **a**r**a**bs, Om**a**n, and Ir**a**q

I start the name of an old Saudi king,

> King **A**bdullah, who was King until very recently (2015) per the second hint.

inside of his kingdom I'm twice.

> The **A**r**a**b Kingdom, I suppose?

I am involved when a hen does its thing,

> That is, l**a**ying eggs.

or when you have been told the price.

> G**a**sping or f**a**inting, perhaps?

When you need God, you can use me at will,

> When you need to pr**a**y? H**a**lleluj**a**h?

children light matches in awe.

> In **a**we! (yes, I know this one is weak)

I'm there when you're lost, when you neuter or kill,

> When you're **a**str**a**y, when you c**a**str**a**te or sp**a**y, and when you **a**ss**a**ssin**a**te or  elimin**a**te.

assert that your word is the law.

> When you **a**ffirm it, or **a**nnounce it.

Comment: Augh, it's stuck in my head again.

Comment: @jafe It's a good song, okay?? I feel like I'm barking up the wrong tree though, but none of the other Saudi Kings fit your description...

Answer (score -1):

Is the answer

> M

I can be found in a Bee Gees refrain

> Massachussets

and in a baccarat deck.

> 

Bavarian beer and in any old sayin',

> 

arabs, Oman and Iraq.

> United Arab Emirates

I start the name of an old Saudi king,

> 

inside of his kingdom I'm twice.

> Mecca and Medina

I am involved when a hen does its thing,
or when you have been told the price.

When you need God, you can use me at will,

> Amen

children light matches in awe.

> 

I'm there when you're lost, when you neuter or kill,

> Missing, emasculate, murder

assert that your word is the law.

> Claim

Comment: Why is my answer down voted? I answered before the 4th hint was put up. I know there's a lot of loopholes but I was just taking a guess!